# It seems that the output of sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances is different to the formula on doc

Tags: machine-learning, distance, metric

The [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) of `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances()` gives this formula

> dist(x, y) = sqrt(dot(x, x) - 2 * dot(x, y) + dot(y, y)).

Apply this formula to this example

```
X = [[0, 1],
     [2, 3]]

Y = [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]]

np.dot(X,X) - 2*np.dot(X,Y) + np.dot(Y,Y)
```

gives this result

```
array([[ 3,  5],
       [-1,  1]])
```

whilst calling sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances()

```
euclidean_distances(X , Y, squared = True)
```

gives

```
array([[ 2., 18.],
       [ 2.,  2.]])
```

It seems that the output of `euclidean_distances()` is not consistent to the formula from the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sklearn docs' formula says it is applying to row vectors $x$ and $y$.  When you call `np.dot` on the matrices $X$ and $Y$ it takes the matrix product.

EDIT (responding to question in comments):
It's not straightforward, as the row-vs-row operations needed aren't quite the usual matrix operations.  The source code for `euclidean_distances` does it this way (except that it does lots of input checks, operates on sparse inputs when possible, etc.):

```
(X*X).sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] - 2*np.dot(X,Y.T) + (Y*Y).sum(axis=1)[np.newaxis, :]
```

That's not exactly straightforward itself, so I'll say a little more.  Say $X$ has $m$ rows and $Y$ has $n$ rows.  The middle term, by taking $Y^T$, gives us a $m\times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-entry is the dot product of the $i$th row of $X$ with the $j$th *row* of $Y$.  In the other terms, `*` on numpy arrays is the coordinate-wise product; summing along rows gives us the rows' squared-norms.  The `newaxis` is a nice trick: casting the first term to now be a $m\times 1$ matrix, adding it to the middle term's $m\times n$ matrix actually adds it to every column of that matrix (without needing to actually build the matrix of repeated columns of $X$'s squared-norms).  And of course similarly for the last term: casting to a $1\times n$ matrix makes it add to every row of the result.

Comment: To reproduce the result of sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances, which numpy method/function should I use for the dot in that formula?

Comment: I'll add it to the answer, since the formatting will be nicer there.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Is "coordinate-wise product" same to "Hadamard product"?

Comment: @czlsws Happy to help.  Yes, it is also called the Hadamard product, Schur product, entry-wise product (erm, in fact perhaps "entry-wise" is better than "coordinate-wise").